# How to restrict edit script to run in specific column _google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a script in sheets to allow multiple selection. The script works but when i go to edit a cell somewhere else on the sheet the information disappears. I need to run this script only for column 5, so if something is documented elsewhere, it wont keep disappearing.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="TRACKER- Relaunch")
        newValue=e.value;
    oldValue=e.oldValue;
    if(!e.value) {
        activeCell.setValue("");
    }
    else {
        if (!e.oldValue) {
            activeCell.setValue(newValue);
        }
        else {
            if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
                activeCell.setValue(oldValue+','+newValue);
            }
            else {
                activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function in an `if` statement which checks that the changed cell is in the 5th columns and that you are in the correct sheet.

```
function onEdit( event ){
  const columnOfCell = event.columnStart;
  const currentSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const targetSheetName = "TRACKER- Relaunch";

  if( columnOfCell === 5 && currentSheetName === targetSheetName){
    // work your magic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart==5 && sh.getName()=="TRACKER- Relaunch") { 
    if(!e.value) {//this doesn't make much sense
      e.range.setValue("");
    }else if(!e.oldValue) {//nor does this
      e.range.setValue(e.value);
    }else if(e.oldValue.indexOf(e.value)==-1) {
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue + ',' + e.value);
    }else{ 
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
    }
  }
}
```